# Changing the target anchor of a link on click - single page layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a single page layout portfolio website and one of the features I'd like to include is a fixed button that when clicked will go to the next section (portfolio piece, contact, about, whatever happens to be next) when clicked. Typically for this kind of layout I would use a smooth scroll function and then just have individual anchors targeted from different buttons but I've never tried to make one button that will do it all. Is there a way to change the target anchor of this button on every click or is there a better method for this that I'm not aware of? Apologize, I have no real code to show because I'm not sure how to approach this from the start, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On each click, run a simple javascript function that grabs the current position/section id and determines which section the user should see see next, assuming you want the user to view sections in a specified order.

Comment: Hmmmm that at least gives me some direction, a starting point, I'll start trying to crack the code on it, thanks! If you or anyone else happens to run across a page where this is utilized post the link up here if you can, never hurts to check the code of someone who's already done it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can divide your one-pager into separate sections in equal length. Then have a fixed button on the page that scroll to the next section as you click.

Answer (score 0):

i would say that you need to have an array of Targets.
and something like :

```
var targets = ["asd", "dsa", "123", "321"];
$("#SomeAnchor").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //prevents firing the event of the <a> tag
        var currentTarget = $(this).attr('href');   //takes current anchor target
        var nextTarget = null;
        for (var i =0; i < Targets.length; i++) {   //loop every target
             if (Targets[i] === currentTarget ) {   //if this is the current target, get next
                 if (i === Targets.length - 1) {  //if i stands for the last position in Targets
                     nextTarget = Targets[0]; //first target again
                 } else {
                     nextTarget = Targets[i + 1]; //take next target
                 }
             }  
        }
//i dont get what you want to do next, but now you can manage your targets.
//of course that it must not be targets array and it can be array of elements
// like $(".item") <- this will give you an array of elements containing class named 'item'
    });
```

code is not tested n i wrote it here because i need to update my WebStorm first...